# Difference: Surely vs Indeed

Tags: difference

What does each mean when used as the first word in a statement/sentence?  Is the emphasis the same or does one indicate more forcefulness/certainty than the other?  Is surely suitable below or does it imply a question?  Are both equal to an exclamation mark(!) ?

> e.g.  Indeed/Surely, to those who disbelieve, a nod is as good as a
>   wink to a blind horse.

Comment: Surely is [more amenable to bad puns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A5t5_O8hdA).

Answer (score 1):

[Indeed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indeed?s=t) is used when the statement that follows is reaffirming or reinforcing a point that was made earlier.

[Surely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/surely?s=t) can have that meaning, but it also frequently implies contradiction or disbelief: "Surely this can't be what he meant." (Note that "Surely", like "obviously", frequently means that the statement which follows is not actually certain or obvious--only that the speaker wishes it were!)

Either of these words might be appropriate in your example sentence, but it would depend on the context. The idiomatic expression ["A nod is as good as a wink to a blind horse](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Sayings/Quizzes/Talking_1/A_nod_is_as_good_as_a_wink_to_a_blind_horse_937.htm)" means that a small hint will be enough to communicate the intended meaning.

If the previous sentence were:

> James' single raised eyebrow said everything.

I would think "Indeed" would make more sense.

If the previous sentence were:

> It's not always necessary to spell everything out explicitly.

Then I would think "Surely" would be a more appropriate beginning for the sentence.

Both could be followed by an exclamation point, or could not; again, it depends on the context. Neither one would necessarily communicate the meaning of the exclamation point without the punctuation itself.